# Is there a more refined way of casting the ColumnNames of a Datable to a List, other my approach in c#?

Tags: c#, database, list, oledb

```
string tablename = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
string constring = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = " + _filenamelbl.Text;
dt = new DataTable();
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring))
{
    using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]",tablename), con))
    {
        da.Fill(dt);
    }
}
List<string> fields = new List<string>();
foreach (DataColumn v in dt.Columns)
    fields.Add(v.ColumnName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Linq to get the column names:

```
var fields = dt.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().Select(c => c.ColumnName).ToList();
```

This uses [`OfType<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netcore-3.1) to cast the columns to an enumerable collection (of `DataColumn`), then applies [`Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1) to take the column names.